# URL rewriting to hide .php and variable names

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have learned about URL Rewriting using `.htaccess`, very recently. As a beginner it has become difficult task for me :(

I can rewrite a specific url, like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule    ^nothing/?$    abc.php    [NC,L]
```

But I'm not satisfied with it and need your help.

My .php files are kept in a folder named `files`. So I have URLs like:

```
www.mysite.com/files/login.php?lf=student
www.mysite.com/files/login.php?lf=admin
www.mysite.com/files/s_home.php
www.mysite.com/files/recharge.php
```

What I want is simple:

```
mysite.com/login
mysite.com/login
mysite.com/s_home
mysite.com/recharge
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: Where is the query (lf=student, for example) in the incoming URL?

Comment: Please clarify your question, I didn't get it.

Comment: Your examples `www.mysite.com/files/login.php?lf=student` have a query: `lf=student`. Where is that query here: `mysite.com/login`. It's clear the script is the name of the folder, but where is the query?

Comment: query is hidden. can't i hide that query using .htaccess? I don't know though.

Comment: If it isn't in the incoming URL, there is no way to pass it to the script. And yes, it will be mapped silently, but it has to exist somewhere.

Comment: You should have URLs like this one: `mysite.com/login/student` or `mysite.com/login/admin`. That way `admin`, for example, is the parameter of the query passed to the script.

Comment: ok, got it. can you post your solution as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Even though this will do as you've asked, why are you trying to hide the `.php` extension?

Comment: because I want to hide that I'm using php. Thanks for your answer, I'm going to try with this ...

Comment: It doesn't help anyways, the "server software" hearder will show that you use php, unless of course you have  access to the configuration settings

Answer (score 0):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/files/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.+)/?$ /files/$1.php?lf=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/files/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /files/$1.php [L]
```